# Authentication to host '' for user 'root' using method

Tags: mysql, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

i'm trying to launch my application but i end up getting this error message

**{"Authentication to host '' for user 'root' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user 'root'@'DESKTOP-4TLD649' (using password: YES)"}**

i have tried with typing

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON . TO root@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'root';
```

but it did not work for me. i just get an syntax error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TO root@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'root'' at line 1
```

Comment: I suggest you give application's connection string to the DB, ensure the DB name provided in connection string exactly matches with actual DB name and have proper credentials (including sufficient permissions).

Answer (score 0):

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON databasename.tablename TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'root';